# is there a way to make mongoose cast `Date` type as number (timestamp) on the JS side?

Tags: javascript, mongoose

In Mongoose, there is the `Date` schema type which is exactly what I want, except one thing: on the javascript side (no in mongodb) it gets/sets `Date` instances for the field's value.

Is there an option, or other schema type, which will allow it to set/get `number` scalar type instead (like if I was doing `const val = Number(doc.dateField)`), while still keeping it as an `ISODate` in mongodb?

I started to create a custom mongoose schema type for that, but if there was a native mongoose option/type for that I'd prefer.

*UPDATE - here is a code sample to show what I want*:

```
const docSchema = new Schema({dateField: Date}})
const Doc = mongoose.model('Doc', docSchema)
// ...
const doc = Doc.findOne(...)

typeof doc.dateField // I want this to be number, without conversion from my side
```

Comment: If i understand correctly you want to transform `2018-10-24T02:51:02.137Z` to a timestamp `1540349462137` ?

Comment: Well, not really. I want:
```
const docSchema = new Schema({dateField: Date}})
const Doc = mongoose.model('Doc', docSchema)

const doc = Doc.findOne(...)

typeof doc.dateField // I want this to be number, without conversion from my side
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `get` and `set` for the `dateField` in the schema as

```
const docSchema = new Schema({
  dateField: {
    type: Date,
    get: (value: Date) => {
      return value.getTime();
    },
    set: (value: number) => {
      return new Date(value);
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: You meant, `dateField: {type: Date, get... set, ...}` right? And so, there is no such option right?

Comment: I didn't see any schema option defined in the mongoose ORM code except adding set and get.

Comment: @Huafu but if you see the code of mongoose where mentioned that it sets schema option for the key.

Comment: I don't understand your last sentence sorry :-/

Comment: What I meant by my first comment is that your code needs fixing. You put get and set outside of the field definition... I've just fixed it in your answer